# Number of ways to divide into 2 football teams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Number of ways to divide n boys onto two football teams of $\frac{n}{2}$ each? Here n is even

Attempt: Is it just $n \choose \frac{n}{2} $. I am getting confused whether should I divide by 2 or not. Is this question any different from having 20 chocolates and putting them in 2 bags so that each contains 10 chocolates. Is this just a generalization of this?

Comment: One way to check your answer is to pick small $n$. Like $n=2$.  Now, there's only one way to create teams (clearly).  What does your formula say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the teams are labeled, then the answer is 
$$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$
However, if they are not labeled, the answer is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$
The reason is that when you select a particular group of boys to form a team, you are also choosing the opposing team.  Therefore, you are selecting the same two teams twice, once when you select a particular group of boys to be on a team and once when you choose the opponents of that group of boys to be on a team.

If the chocolates are distinguishable, then the answer is analogous to the problem above.  If the bags are distinguishable, there are $$\binom{20}{10}$$ ways of distributing the chocolates.  If the bags are indistinguishable, there are half that number of ways to distribute the chocolates.

Comment: Yeah the bags are distinct. But just divide into two football teams are given. Does that mean they are labelled or not?

Comment: @Amrita Usually this wording means that the teams are not labelled.

Comment: If the chocolates are distinct and the bags are distinct (say one is red and the other is blue), the answer $\binom{20}{10}$ comes from deciding which ten of the chocolates will be placed in the red bag.   If both bags are green, we have half as many choices as to where to place the chocolates since we cannot distinguish between the two choices.  Hence, there are $\frac{1}{2}\binom{20}{10}$ ways of placing ten chocolates each in two indistinguishable bags.  If the chocolates are identical, there is only one way to place ten of them in each bag.

Comment: Thanks so much, got confused while reading integer solutions which does not make sense here at all.